# Mysql 1292: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting this error after I added a generated column on my table.
The query is this:

```
UPDATE aspnetusers SET FirstName = 'somename' WHERE Id = 1;
FirstName column is varchar
Id column is int
```

Where is the db even getting this double?

This error started after I added this generated column:

```
"ALTER TABLE aspnetusers ADD FullName varchar(135) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) VIRTUAL;"
```

If I remove this column, then this error disappears.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
ALTER TABLE aspnetusers 
ADD FullName varchar(135)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(FirstName , ' ' , LastName)) VIRTUAL;
```

MySQL does not use `+` to concatenate strings. The error you get is caused by implicit conversion of strings to numbers.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(FirstName , ' ' , LastName)  VIRTUAL' at line 1

Comment: @victor Try now, expression should be wrapped with `()`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!